# How do I find a printer uri?

Tags: 20.04, printing, canon, cups-lpd

I'm trying to install a Cannon IR-ADV C5035 printer and have been unsuccessful. I believe that the problem is a combination of issues, but one item I know i'm missing is the device "URI".

During the CUPs install, as well as in the printer advanced properties window, it asks for me to specify this "uri" which seems to be a combination of the protocol, network IP, and then a random queue name or subfolder that the printer expects to receive information on. How do I know what the proper URI should be?

Is there a way to manually query the printer to have it return what it's expected URI is?

Thanks in advance for the help!

edit:
Here is the output of lpinfo -v

```
network beh
file cups-brf:/
network socket
network https
network http
network lpd
network ipp
network ipps
direct hp
direct hpfax
```

Comment: A USB connected HP printer should display a device URI beginning `hp:/usb` on the `direct hp` line. Are you using USB?

Comment: Apologies, I forgot you have a Canon. On USB there should be  a `direct usb` line with a URI.

Comment: In this instance I'm trying to connect to the printer over Ethernet/IPv4.

Comment: On ethernet a  URI beginning `network dnssd://` would be expected. The PTB seem to haven't any failth in the usefulness of `lpinfo -v` or its manual page, which is why, I imagine, my original answer was deleted. `lpinfo` lists the available devices. Your problem seems to be that whatever CUPS backend is in the Canon software you have downloaded, it is not detecting the printer.